# Failed To Establish Database Connection using JDBC GetConnection

Tags: database, jdbc, google-apps-script, connection

I have tried so many things over the course of today simply trying to establish a connection to a MySQL database on my VPS. I am not using GoogleCloud so `jdbc.getConnection()` is the correct call.

The same error persists:

> "Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password. (line 11, file ..."

..in this case line 11 is :

`var conn = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:mysql://<IP ADDRESS>:3306/<DBNAME>', '<USER>', '<PWD>');`

I have read on the Google Scripts help page and other threads to whitelist IP ranges. I am using MySQL Community version and I have manually updated the .ini file with the ranges listed. I run Workbench and inspect OPTIONS FILE/Replication.

group_replication_ip_whitelist

and the ranges I specified in the `.ini` don't appear. Just a single range (the field is a single line textbox , which suggests for multi-line you delimit with '\n'

On the face of it, even though the `.ini` file has the required IP ranges Workbench is not seeing them, or at least not displaying them correctly via the GUI.

I am convinced that the user/password are correct and  the IP stated is definitely correct, so there appears to be something else blocking my attempts to connect.

UPDATE... 
I have downloaded the plug-in for Chrome that enables MYSQL connectivity and it connected to the database first time , without issue.
So I am convinced the IP ranges that I have added to the MSQL .ini are simply not being seen by MySQL Server and so Jdbc isnt able to connect....

Is there any other way to determine what the whitelisted IP ranges are within MySQL ... without interrogating ->OPTIONS FILE/Replication..??

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: How do I ask a good question..???!!

Comment: ...I can publish the rest but consider this irrelevant and rather un-necessary...The code is stated above... this is the line that is failing in the script.. I can connect without issue by other means.. but I need this script to work for my application....